# Use ActionLink instead of pure JS for a non-submit button in a form

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for a way to display 3 buttons in a form using only methods from HtmlHelper or AjaxHelper, that is, no extra JavaScript in the view if at all possible.

The scenario here is as follows: I got a form with buttons for submit, preview and cancel (think "create new blog post"). The view so far is

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <fieldset>
       ...        
       <div id="preview-content"></div>
       ...
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
       <input type="button" value="Preview" id="preview-button"/>
       @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", new { Area = "Blog" }, new { @class = "button" })
       ...
   </fieldset>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#preview-button').click(function () {
     $.ajax({
         url: '@Url.Action("Preview", new { Area = "Blog" })',
         type: 'POST',
         data: { title: $('#Title').val(), content: $('#Content').val() },
         success: function (data) {
            $('#preview-content').html(data);
         }
      });
   });
</script>
```

I haven't been able to get rid of the JS using one of the helper functions so far. There are a couple of similar questions on SO, but I don't want to post the form when clicking on preview. The idea here is to post the content and get a partial view that is then added inside the form.

I could, of course, handle this like SO does (display and update the preview constantly), but was wondering if there is a solution to my problem.

Comment: So what are you looking for is just move that javascript to another js file?

Comment: No, the idea is to replace the script part by, say, Ajax.ActionLink("Preview", ...). I don't like the fact that the HTML and the script are tightly coupled through the element ID. By moving this code to a helper method (C#) the ID could be auto-generated, the helper method would emit both, HTML and JS and guarantee that the IDs always match. This would also make for a much more reusable solution and keep the view cleaner. On a side note, this is a private project of mine, at work I have to deal with a huge MVC project that has scripts scattered all over the place, so I try to stear clear now.

Answer (score 1):

I (like most websites) actually PREFER to use jQuery for this types of actions, because the default and basic usage of these pre-built methods fails in many many ways.

What happens if the user walks away for an hour, is then automatically logged out and then hits submit.  A Silent fail with no message to the user if something is wrong.

What happens if the server side validation fails, what message do you give the user?

What happens if the user is on WiFi and gets disconnected from the network, another silent fail with no message to the user something is wrong?

When you get right down to it, even if you fully build out a nice interface using the AjaxHelper, you've just about written the same amount of code.  The only real difference is re-usability and encapsulation.  With AjaxHelper you could create a number of *buttons* that link to javascript methods, if these methods change, you have to change all your AjaxHelpers.  Instead using proper html classes means that these changes are encapsulated in javascript.  YMMV.

For example, I would write your code like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <fieldset>
       ...        
       <div id="preview-content"></div>
       ...
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
       <input type="button" 
              value="Preview" 
              class="js-btn-preview"
              data-preview-url="@Url.Action("Preview", new { Area = "Blog" })"
              data-preview-target="#preview-content"/>
       @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", new { Area = "Blog" }, new { @class = "button" })
       ...
   </fieldset>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.js-btn-preview').click(function () {
     var url = $(this).data("preview-url");
     var target = $(this).data("preview-target");
     var form = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
     $.ajax({
         url: url,
         type: 'POST',
         data: form,
         success: function (data) {
            $(target).html(data);
         }
      });
   });
</script>
```

Now you have a script that can post data from any form, to any url and finally take the result and embed that into a target.  A single highly reusable method that is [decoupled from your html and css](http://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).